# How to add legend in plotnine for multiple curves when "tidy data" is not the issue

Tags: python, ggplot2, plotnine

Several people have asked how to add a legend in `ggplot2` or `plotnine` for multiple curves when the curves differ by the selection of rows to be plotted. The typical answer is to reformat the data as [tidy data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tidy_data). Some examples are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62900745/how-to-add-legend-in-ggplot-plotnine-for-multiple-curves), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40833809/add-legend-to-geom-line-graph-in-r/), and [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/adding-manual-legend-to-ggplot2/41651).

I need multiple lines not because of subsetting the data, but rather because I want to compare smoothing methods. The data are the same for all the lines, so the above answers don't help.

The latter two answers point out that in `ggplot2` in R, the legend can be created by moving the `color` specifier inside `aes(...)`. This is described in detail [here](https://aosmith.rbind.io/2018/07/19/manual-legends-ggplot2/#using-scale_color_identity-to-recognize-color-strings), which is similar to what I want to do.

Is this supposed to work in `plotnine` as well? I tried an example similar to the [previous link](https://aosmith.rbind.io/2018/07/19/manual-legends-ggplot2/#using-scale_color_identity-to-recognize-color-strings). It works fine without the legend:

```py
from plotnine import *
from plotnine.data import *

(ggplot(faithful, aes(x='waiting'))
    + geom_line(stat='density', adjust=0.5, color='red')
    + geom_line(stat='density', color='blue')
    + geom_line(stat='density', adjust=2, color='green')
    + labs(title='Effect of varying KDE smoothing parameter',
           x='Time to next eruption (min)',
           y='Density')
)
```

[image: Graph without legend]

But it fails when I move `color` into `aes` in order to get a legend:

```py
from plotnine import *
from plotnine.data import *

(ggplot(faithful, aes(x='waiting'))
    + geom_line(aes(color='red'), stat='density', adjust=0.5)
    + geom_line(aes(color='blue'), stat='density')
    + geom_line(aes(color='green'), stat='density', adjust=2)
    + labs(title='Effect of varying KDE smoothing parameter',
           x='Time to next eruption (min)',
           y='Density')
    + scale_color_identity(guide='legend')
)
```

This give the error
`PlotnineError: "Could not evaluate the 'color' mapping: 'red' (original error: name 'red' is not defined)"`.

Any suggestions for how to add a legend? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the last link you posted was on the right track but you have to trick python to overcome some of the non-standard evaluation that R does. I was able to get it to work by setting two sets of quotes around the color names:

```
(ggplot(faithful, aes(x='waiting'))
    + geom_line(aes(color="'red'"), stat='density', adjust=0.5)
    + geom_line(aes(color="'blue'"), stat='density')
    + geom_line(aes(color="'green'"), stat='density', adjust=2)
    + labs(title='Effect of ...',
           x='Time to next eruption (min)',
           y='Density')
    + scale_color_identity(guide='legend',name='My color legend')
)
```

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QpihB.png)

And you can make your own labels like the post:

```
(ggplot(faithful,aes(x='waiting'))
 + geom_line(aes(color="'red'"),stat='density',adjust=.5)
 + geom_line(aes(color="'blue'"),stat='density')
 + geom_line(aes(color="'green'"), stat='density',adjust=2)
 +labs(title='Effect of ...',x='Time to next eruption (min)',
       y='Density')
 + scale_color_identity(guide='legend',name='My colors',
                        breaks=['red','blue','green'],
                        labels=['Label 1','Label 2','Label 3']))
```

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/27wZd.png)

Answer (score 1):

Put the colors in quotes e.g `'"red"'` instead of `'red'`.

```
(ggplot(faithful, aes(x='waiting'))
    + geom_line(aes(color='"red"'), stat='density', adjust=0.5)
    + geom_line(aes(color='"blue"'), stat='density')
    + geom_line(aes(color='"green"'), stat='density', adjust=2)
    + labs(title='Effect of varying KDE smoothing parameter',
           x='Time to next eruption (min)',
           y='Density')
    + scale_color_identity(guide='legend')
)
```